# Do you know why my loop + modulo (%) skips numbers in python

Tags: python, loops, modulo

I am trying to do an update every 20 steps but it skips some numbers I don't understand why

```
time=np.linspace(0.1,100,1000)    

for t in time:
    if t % 2 ==0.0:
        print(t, 'ms')
```

Thank you

Comment: Try using np.isclose(t%2,0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This due to the fact that `linespace` does not achieve exact values like `18.0` or `20.0`. Due to floating point calculation there is a small epsilon. You can change your code like the following, then you will hit all the numbers:

```
time=np.linspace(0.1,100,1000)    
epsilon = 0.0001
for t in time:
    if t % 2 < epsilon:
        print(t, 'ms')
```

Another way is to just print out every 20 step (the first print would be but after 19):

```
time=np.linspace(0.1,100,1000)    
epsilon = 0.0001
for i,t in enumerate(time):
    if (i -19) % 20 ==0:
        print(t, 'ms')
```

Output:

```
2.0 ms
4.0 ms
6.0 ms
8.0 ms
10.0 ms
12.0 ms
14.0 ms
16.0 ms
....
```